# Counting the number of solutions of the congruence $x^k\equiv h$ (mod q)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let (h,q)=1, I would like to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
|\{0\leq x<q:x^k\equiv h(\text{mod q})\}|<C(\epsilon)q^\epsilon
$$
for some constant $C(\epsilon)$ depending on $\epsilon$. The first thing to observe is $(x,q)=1$. I tried to extract something from the equation $a^k\equiv b^k$(mod q), while the only thing I can see is that this can't happen if $|a^k-b^k|<q$, due to my lack of knowledge. But this is far away from the answer. I have also tried to factor out $q=p_1^{e_1}...p_k^{e_k}$ and only consider modulo a prime power, but I doubt if it works, even if it works I still don't have an idea how to solve the case even when q is a prime.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort. For a reference to this problem, see page 72 in Vaughan's book, The Hardy-Littlewood Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when doing elementary modular arithmetic, you must know at least the basic properties of the ring $\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z$, in particular the Chinese remainder theorem: if $q={p_1}^{e_1}...{p_r}^{e_r}$ (product of powers of distinct primes), there is a ring isomorphism $\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z \cong \mathbf Z/{p_1}^{e_1}\mathbf Z \times ...\mathbf Z/{p_r}^{e_r}\mathbf Z$, which implies in particular an isomorphism of multiplicative groups $(\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)^* \cong (\mathbf Z/{p_1}^{e_1}\mathbf Z)^* \times ...(\mathbf Z/{p_r}^{e_r}\mathbf Z)^*$, where $(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^*$ denotes the group of invertible elements of the ring $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. Given $(h,q)=1$, to solve $x^k \equiv h$ mod $q$ is then equivalent to solve ${[x_i]}^k=[h_i]$ in ($\mathbf Z/{p^{e_i}}\mathbf Z)^*$ for all $i=1,..., r$, where $[y_i]$ denotes the class of $y$ mod ${p_i}^{e_i}$.

We are thus brought back to solve @ ${[x_i]}^k=[h_i]$ in $(\mathbf Z/{p^{e_i}}\mathbf Z)^*$. The structure of the latter group is known : it is cyclic of order $\phi({p^{e_i}})$ (where $\phi$ is the Euler function), except when $p=2, e_i\ge 3$, in which case it is $\cong (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z,+)\times (\mathbf Z/2^{e_i-2}\mathbf Z,+)$. For simplicity, we'll consider only the cyclic case (the exceptional non cyclic case is just a matter of book keeping), and use repeatedly the fact that a cyclic group of order $g$ admits a unique subgroup of order $g'$, for any $g'$ dividing $g$. Denote by $ord (.)$ the order of an element in a group. Here in $(\mathbf Z/{p^{e_i}}\mathbf Z)^*$, @ admits a solution iff  $ord[x_i]=k.ord [h_i]$ divides $\phi({p^{e_i}})$.  If such is the case, the number of solutions of @ is also the number of solutions of ${[y_i]}^k=1$, i.e. $k$.

In conclusion, *in the non exceptional case*, suppose moreover that $q$ is odd (just to avoid petty book keeping). The original congruence in $(\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)^*$ admits a solution iff $k.ord [h_i]$ divides $\phi({p^{e_i}})$ for $i=1,...,r$, in which case the total number of solutions is $k^r$.

Comment: Sorry I think there is some misunderstanding: I think what you are doing is considering all the solutions with (h,q)=1, but I intended to mean h is fixed. A simple check with k=2,q=6 gives an opposite answer. Correct me if I am not right.

Comment: No, I consider $h, q, k$ as given, and $x$ as the only variable. From this point of view, your question decomposes naturally in 2 steps : 1) Existence of a solution  2) Number of solutions . It seems that I made a slight mistake in my "book keeping" concerning the prime 2 (as usual with 2). See my edited conclusion, which takes care of your "counter-example".

Comment: I understand your solution now, thanks!

Comment: By the way, I think you can also bound the number of solutions in @ by k from fundamental theorem of algebra, correct?

Comment: What do you call "fundamental theorem of algebra" ?

Comment: The equation @ has at most k roots over $Z_{p_i}$, given the case $e_i=1$, but I think one can give a similar bound for the case $e_1>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if this is *that* , it has not any "fundamental" character. But it is worth coming back to the proof to see precisely what conditions are needed. To speak of roots of a polynomial, you need to work at least in a ring $R$ (with 2 operations, + and $\times$). Your polynomial $f(X)\in R[X]$ then reads $f(X)=a_n X^n +...+a_0$, where $a_i \in R$ . The usual proof of the "fundamental thm." starts like this: if $y\in R$ is a root of $f$, then $(X-y)$ must divide $f(X)$. But how do you prove this lemma ? If you think of it, the only known way is to use euclidian division in $R[X]$, i.e. $f(X)=(X-y)g(X)+r$, the key point being that the degree of the remainder $r$ must be strictly less than the degree of the divisor, so that here $r\in R$, hence $r=0$ if $y$ is a root. But to perform euclidian division, at least you have to divide by non zero coefficients at some point, i.e. you need an extra operation, namely *division*, which turns your ring into a *field*. Starting from a ring $R$ which is a *domain* (i.e. $xy=0$ implies $x$ or $y=0$), you can embed $R$ into its field of fractions, but not all rings are domains. For instance, $Z/nZ$ is a domain iff $n$ is prime, iff $Z/nZ$ is a field.

Actually, the original question in your post is *not* field theoretical. The Chinese remainder thm. is ring theoretical, but from that on, the rest of the study is purely group theoretical.